# Union is grabbing all ranges in between my selections

Tags: vba, excel, powerpoint

Here's the entire code in case you want to look at it: https://pastebin.com/TbewRRCc . My problem is that after checking, my Collection is indeed only composed of the columns I want it have. So If I have three columns I want to be in there, columnsToCopy.Count will = 3, also when I just copy columnToCopy(3).Copy the result will be just one column. But when I go through The loop to make a Union of these three columns, all the columns in between these columns will also be in the union.

For example. Say I'm copying Column 1, 13 and 30. The Pasted Table will be all Columns from 1 to 30. This is not what I want. I want only Column 1,13,and 30... So three columns in total for this particular Colelction.

Any ideas on what may be causing my problem, and how to fix it?

```
            For arrayLoop = LBound(iq_Array) To UBound(iq_Array)
                ' Take copy of potential ref and adjust to standard if required
                checkStr = iq_Array(arrayLoop)
                If hasIQs And Left(checkStr, 3) <> "iq_" Then checkStr = "iq_" & checkStr

                ' Look for existence of corresponding column in local copy array
                pCol = 0
                For iCol = 2 To colNumb
                    If checkStr = IQRef(iCol) Then
                        pCol = iCol
                        Exit For
                    End If
                Next iCol

                If pCol > 0 Then
                    ' Paste the corresponding column into the forming table
                    columnsToCopy.Add ShRef.Columns(pCol).EntireColumn
                End If

            Next arrayLoop

            If columnsToCopy.Count > 1 Then                   'data was added
                ' Copy table

Dim unionVariable As Range

Set unionVariable = columnsToCopy(1)


For k = 1 To columnsToCopy.Count
    Set unionVariable = xlApp.Union(unionVariable, columnsToCopy(k))
Next k

unionVariable.Copy
Next k

unionVariable.Copy
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on your explanation (collection containing only the columns you want) this works for me

---

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub TestUnion()
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet, k As Long
    Dim unionVariable As Range, columnsToCopy As Collection

    Set ws1 = Sheet1
    Set ws2 = Sheet2

    Set columnsToCopy = New Collection

    columnsToCopy.Add ws1.UsedRange.Columns(1)
    columnsToCopy.Add ws1.UsedRange.Columns(3)
    columnsToCopy.Add ws1.UsedRange.Columns(5)

    Set unionVariable = columnsToCopy(1)

    For k = 2 To columnsToCopy.Count
        Set unionVariable = Union(unionVariable, columnsToCopy(k))
    Next k

    unionVariable.Copy ws2.Cells(1)     'copy AND paste
End Sub
```

---

I just changed the For loop to start from 2, and performed the paste on the same line as the copy

Comment: So you're saying that when you paste that it only pastes 3 columns? Columns 1, 3 and 5? I really don't understand why it isn't working for me then... Would I be able to upload the files I'm working with so you can see what I'm talking about?

Comment: [PPT Slide Virus Scan](https://www.virustotal.com/#/file/ff5125e3234eb4795dbd330be554dbc90197eafb60cea1cf036da9389a92165f/detection)  , [Excel File Virus Scan](https://www.virustotal.com/#/file/24d41c015f53fe0621d91a0db8661701b6e858e98edc9e961f703e1da8706a58/detection) , [PPT Slide File](https://filetea.me/n3wZluzhVXFTpmjlUPmTxzKew) , [Excel File](https://filetea.me/n3wG3zbxnKoRuuYhonhFf7PHQ)